# Node Js Joi validate object that contains list of same object

Tags: node.js, typescript, joi

Suppose I have the following object represented in json:

```
{
  "name": "Joe",
  "childrens": [
    {
      "name": "Marie",
      "childrens": [
        {
          "name": "Paul"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Nick",
      "childrens": [
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I create a schema to validate an object that contains a list of the same object?

Comment: This list is infinitely recursive?

Comment: yes, this list is infinitely recursive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Joi.lazy()` method to implement a recursive schema like:

```
const Person = Joi.object({
  name: joi.string().required(),
  children: joi.array().items(joi.lazy(() => Person).description('My Schema'))
});
```

In newer versions of Joi you have to use `Joi.link()` in order to link an `id` of a schema.

```
const personSchema = joi
  .object({
    name: joi.string().required(),
    children: joi.array().items(joi.link("#person"))
  })
  .id("person");
```

Note I renamed your `childrens` property to `children`.

Comment: When I do that I get an erroer saying:
Property 'lazy' does not exist on type 'Root

I'm importing like this:
import * as Joi from "joi";